# SQL tuning, long running query + rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-performance

I have million record in database table having account no, address and many more columns. I want 100 rows in sorting with desc order, I used rownum for this, but the query is taking a long time to execute, since it scans the full table first make it in sorted order then apply the rownum.

What is the solution to minimize the query execution time?

For example:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         acc_no, address 
     from 
         customer 
     order by 
         acc_no desc) 
where 
    ROWNUM <= 100;
```

Comment: Do you have index defined on the customer table?

Comment: As Sumit says you should have an index, i assume acc_no is unique? if it's not your primary key it should at least be covered in the index

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: yes, index is defined, I have query(having joins to multiple table) which return 3 lakh record, but in UI I want to display only 100 record, but since the query itself taking long time to execute , so after applying rownum to outer query it taking same amount of time,  any solution for this.
@ marc_s : it is oracle DBMS

Answer (score 2):

From past experience I found that the TOP works best for this scenario.

Also you should always select the columns you need only and avoid using the all card (*)

```
SELECT TOP 100 [acc_no], [address] FROM [customer] ORDER BY [acc_no] DESC
```

Useful resources about TOP, LIMIT and even ROWNUM.

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use index on acc_no column.

1. If you have an index already present on acc_no, check if that's being used during query execution or not by verifying the query execution plan.

To create a new index if not present, use below query :

```
Create index idx1 on customer(acc_no); -- If acc_no is not unique
Create unique index idx1 on customer(acc_no); -- If acc_no is unique. Note: Unique index is faster.
```

2. If in explain plan output you see "Full table scan", then it is a case that optimizer is not using the index.

Try with a hint first :

```
select /*+ index(idx1) */ * from 
(select 
     acc_no, address 
 from 
     customer 
 order by 
     acc_no desc) 
where 
ROWNUM <= 100;
```

3. If the query with hint above returned results quickly, then you need to check why optimizer is ignoring your index deliberately. One probable reason for this is outdated statistics. Refresh the statistics.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider getting your top account numbers in an inner query / in-line view such that you only perform the joins on those 100 customer records.  Otherwise, you could be performing all the joins on the million+ rows, then sorting the million+ results to get the top 100.  Something like this may work.

```
    select .....
    from customer
    where customer.acc_no in (select acc_no from
                        (select inner_cust.acc_no
                         from   customer inner_cust
                         order by inner_cust.acc_no desc
                        )
                    where rownum <= 100)
       and ...
```

Or, if you are using 12C you can use `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY`

```
    select .....
    from customer
    where customer.acc_no in (select inner_cust.acc_no
                              from   customer inner_cust
                              order by inner_cust.acc_no desc
                              fetch first 100 rows only
                            )
       and ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the result within 100ms, but MAKE SURE that there is index on column ACC_NO. There also can be combined index on ACC_NO+other colums, but ACC_NO MUST be on the first position in the index. You have to see "range scan" in execution plan. Not "full table scan", not "skip scan". You can probably see nested loops in execution plan (that will fetch ADDRESSes from table). You can improve speed even more by creating combined index for ACC_NO, ADDRESS (in this order). In such case Oracle engine does not have to read the table at all, because all the information is contained in the index. You can compare it in execution plan.

```
select top 100 acc_no, address 
    from customer 
    order by acc_no desc
```

Comment: I am not sure, in such case your SQL is correct, only take care of proper setup of indexes